# checking if 2 elements exist and moving ul inside another div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if `div#tab7` AND `ul.Gal_3` exists on the page. If it does then i would like to move the entire contents of `ul.Gal_3` within `div#tab7`

Here is my code for the conditional part, but unsure on the last bit?
Also is there a performance decrease in doing this?

```
if ($('div#tab7').length > 0 && ('ul.Gal_3').length > 0) {
    //it exists so now move the contents of the UL inside the div#tab7
}
```

Comment: this is valid, what's the problem?

Comment: missing a `$` in front of `('ul.Gal_3')`

Comment: There's no reason to use `div#tab7`...just use `#tab7`.

Comment: You don't need to check if they exist, just move their content. If there are no such elements just nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to do it like this:

```
if ($('div#tab7').length > 0 && $('ul.Gal_3').length > 0) {
    $('#tab7').append($('ul.Gal_3'));
}
```

Check if the tab and gallery exists then move the gallery inside the div#tab7.

Comment: I don't think you need the `if` statement. If either of the jquery selectors don't match anything, nothing will happen and nothing will fail, so checking beforehand is redundant. Just try the append without the `if` statement. If you need to do other things based on the condition, then you obviously need the `if`, but I'm pretty sure it's not necessary

Comment: thanks @Ian I think you are right.. But might be adding more logic to the block, so might need it.

Comment: Sounds good, just wanted to point it out :) And again, you don't need `div#tab7` - you can just use `#tab7`

Answer (score -1):

Copying content:

```
$('div#tab7').html($('ul.Gal_3').html());
```

Moving content:

```
var dest = $('ul.Gal_3');
$('div#tab7').html(dest.html());
dest.html('');
```

Comment: It's not good to use `.html` to copy/move content. jQuery event handlers and data are lost.